# gganimate a frequency histogram to show change after each additional sample

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, gganimate

I have the following data set representing repeated samples of a population and the subsequent sample mean:

```
data.frame(sample = 1:50, mu = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 0, sd = 1))
```

I've made a frequency histogram in ggplot using the following code:

```
data.frame(sample = 1:50, mu = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 0, sd = 1)) %>% 
ggplot(data = ., aes(mu)) + 
geom_histogram()
```

[image]

I am attempting to animate this histogram using `gganimate`, where each additional sample changes the frequency distribution of means in the plot. I'm at a loss of how to do this however.

I have attempted this but the result is not as desired:

```
data.frame(sample = 1:50, mu = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 0, sd = 1)) %>% 
ggplot(data = ., aes(x = mu)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  transition_time(sample) +
  ease_aes("linear") +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_fade()
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want the histogram to build up over time adding a new sample with each step. If taht is what you want, this can be achieved like so:

The basis idea is to split by sample and then accumulate the samples to frames, i.e. in frame 1 only sample 1 is show, in frame 2 sample 1 and 2, .....

```r
library(gganimate)
#> Lade nötiges Paket: ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(42)

# example data
df <- data.frame(sample = 1:500, mu = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 0, sd = 1))

df_ani <- df %>% 
  split(.$sample) %>% 
  accumulate(~ bind_rows(.x, .y)) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "frame") %>% 
  mutate(frame = as.integer(frame))
head(df_ani)
#>   frame sample         mu
#> 1     1      1  1.3709584
#> 2     2      1  1.3709584
#> 3     2      2 -0.5646982
#> 4     3      1  1.3709584
#> 5     3      2 -0.5646982
#> 6     3      3  0.3631284

p_gg <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = mu)) +
  geom_histogram()
p_gg
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

```r
p_anim <- ggplot(data = df_ani, aes(x = mu)) +
  geom_histogram()

anim <- p_anim + transition_manual(frame) +
  ease_aes("linear") +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_fade()
anim
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work well. However, it appears to break down with larger sample sizes. For example, if we increase the sample size from 50 to 5000, the animate chart is the same overall shape as the regular ggplot, but the frequency count is substantially inflated?

Comment: Hi. Yes. You are right. That's not what we want. The problem with my approach is that the histogram is computed for the inflated dataset, in which the samples are replicated with each additional frame. As a consequnce the frequency is inflated, i.e. for a sample size of 50 sample 1 is counted 50 times in the final frame, while sample 50 is only counted once. For the moment I have no simple solution to this problem. But I will think about it.

Comment: Hi. After looking around. The simple solution is to switch to `transition_manual`. I edited my code, increased the sample size to 500 and added the ggplot for the non-inflated df for comparison.